# JavaScript - Is there any way to dynamically create a new instance of a object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am working on a small project where by i need to create objects with form field data. In short i have a constructor function that retrieves values from each form field like this:

```
var Task = function() {
  this.title = document.getElementById("task-title").value;
  this.date = document.getElementById("task-date").value;
  this.option = document.getElementById("task-option").value;
}
```

What i need is create a NEW instance of object each time somebody clicks the submit button. What i have so far is this:

```
var submitBtn = document.getElementById('#someID');
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var newTask = new Task();           
});
```

This works in that it create an object, but the objects gets overridden each time the button is pressed. I need a new instance of the object to be created each time the buttoned is pressed.

Is this possible ? if not is there a more viable alternative to constructor functions? Thank you so much.

Comment: using var Task = function(){} is a singleton and an instance in itself. if you want multiple instances, create a function Task(){} and declare it like var task = new Task()

Comment: Uh? `new Task();` will always created a new object. What do you mean by "the objects gets overridden"? What exactly are you doing with `newTask`?

Comment: @a.j.: `var Task = function() {}` and `function Task() {}` are the same thing. The OP is already doing `new Task()` too.

Comment: You are creating a new instance each time you click. You just never do anything with it before it falls out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining that newTask variable inside the enventlistener and then immediately assigning the new Task to it. Your code is doing everything you told it to do. Namely, create a new variable and assign a new instance of task to it. After the function ends the newTask is destroyed because there's nothing to do anymore and nowhere else in your code are you able to reach it.

Why dont you try this:

```
var submitBtn = document.getElementById('#someID');
var myTasks = [];
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  myTasks.push(new Task());           
});
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! Works like a charm. You and @Johnny John replied at the same time but as i mentioned in my comment to him i am giving it to you as you have a few less asweres in your profile. Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are always putting the value in the same var, you will need make a array with your objects, so you don't lose your old object

```
var submitBtn = document.getElementById('#someID');
var newTask = [];
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   newTask.push(new Task());           
});
```

Comment: Johnny John, Thank you for your reply, it worked beautifully. @RobbyD gave me the same answer just about the same time you did. He has less answers so  in an attempt to be fair i'm giving it to him. Thank you for taking the time.